# Tecla F1 JavaHelp

Tags: java, java-swing

En cualquier programa o aplicación en la mayoría de las ocasiones al pulsar la tecla F1 se abre un sistema de ayuda referente a esa utilidad.

Estoy en mi proyecto y he creado un sistema de ayuda, el cual debería abrirse al pulsar F1 pero no...
1) Falla al pulsar F1, no hace nada.

2) Tengo un menú con un botón y sobre abre el sistema de ayuda al hacer click por 2 vez.

Código:

```
private void lanzarAyuda(){
        try{
            //Carga el fichero de ayuda.
            File fichero = new File("sistema_ayuda" + File.separator + "helpset.hs");
            URL hsURL = fichero.toURI().toURL();

            //Crea el HelpSet.
            HelpSet helpset = new HelpSet(getClass().getClassLoader(), hsURL);
            HelpBroker hb = helpset.createHelpBroker();
            //Mostrar el sistema de ayuda al pulsar F1.
            hb.enableHelpOnButton(button_ayuda, "principal", helpset);
            hb.enableHelpKey(getRootPane(), "principal", helpset);

            //Colocamos la posicion de la ventana (Posicion p).
            hb.setSize(new Dimension(800,600));
            //Colocamos el tamaño de la ventana (Dimension d).
            hb.setLocation(new Point(250,90));
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

private void button_ayudaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        lanzarAyuda();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En cuanto a tu falla de que no hace nada al pulsar F1 podría deberse a que el Sistema no está reconociendo la pulsación de la Tecla correspondiente. Puedes probar agregando el siguiente método a tu programa:

```
public static void addF1ListenerWindowDialog() 
{
   ActionListener F1Action = new ActionListener() {
    @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //Todo lo que quieres que haga al pulsar F1
        }
    };
    windowDialog.getRootPane().registerKeyboardAction(F1Action,
    KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F1, 0),
    JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
}
```